# How feasible would it be to create a bash shell in a browser?

Tags: javascript, flash, unix

Primarily, I'm a C/C++ programmer on Unix machines... But I'd kill for browser based shell access to a linux box...

So, the question is: How hard would it be, and what approaches would be the best for building real shell level access into a web page? Flash? Javascript?

I know this is really all opinion, but I'm curious if people think it might be possible?

Comment: Neat, but I want a REAL bash shell... :)

Comment: Well, it shows that it can be done in javascript ;) At least the front-end side of things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few scripts that can do this :

- http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/
- http://anyterm.org/index.html
- http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mressl/webshell/index.html
- http://www.techenclave.com/operating-systems/web-based-shell-interfaces-870.html

Comment: Except for anyterm, all the other links are no longer working.

Answer (score 2):

You could embed a [Java SSH applet](http://www.javassh.org/space/start)...

Answer (score 0):

This is already done in [Cloud9](https://c9.io) project. You can run terminal application in the browser.