# Embedding a Bash shell in my Flask application?

Tags: javascript, python, bash, flask

I know this is kind of weird and not secure at all, but is there a way of displaying a bash shell with a remote control on the machine where the webapp is running ?
I would like to have a bash interpreter running directly in the webapplication in flask, does anyone knows how to do such a thing ?

Thanks a lot,
If my post wasn't clear enough just tell me and I will try to improve it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619156/how-feasible-would-it-be-to-create-a-bash-shell-in-a-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an interface that looks like you opened a new terminal. To do so, create a form, and everytime you hit Enter, you send this data (using jQuery.ajax for instance) to the server.

On the server side, use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to run the commands you get from the server. You might need to parse this data (something like: my_string.split(' ')) in order to get the argument in a list. You can return the result of that command using: subprocess.check_output in a JSON data type to the client. With Javascript (and jQuery) you can now parse that data and display it wherever you want.